# How to make arrays/json appear in the correct way

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have tried to fix this issue myself by looking around. But I don't seem to be able to figure out how to make my encoded json appear correctly.

This is my code that produces the json:

```
//Define messages
$messages = array();
$message = array();
$message["role"] = "system";
$message["content"] = "this is my content for system";
$message["role"] = "user";
$message["content"] = "this is my content for user";
$messages[] = $message;

// Define data
$data["model"] = "gpt-model";
$data = array();
$data["messages"] = $messages;
$data["temperature"] = 1.15;
```

When I encode these arrays with json. I get this output:

```
{
  "model": "gpt-model",
  "messages": [
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "this is my content for user"
    }
 ],
 "temperature": 1.15
 }
```

Firstly it completely ignores the 2nd of each `$message["role"]` and `$message["content"]`

Secondly I would like the results to get shown exactly like this:

```
{
  "model": "gpt-model",
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "this is my content for system"
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "this is my content for user"
    }
  ],
  "temperature": 1.15
}
```

I want to understand how I can do this and fix a problem like this in the future. I guess that the identical names cause an issue. I know that in PHP the latest variable will be the one that is used.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: `$messages = [ [ 'role' => 'system', 'content' => '...' ], ['role' => 'user', 'content' => '...' ] ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign to `$messages[]` for each nested array. Otherwise you're only pushing the last value of `$message` to `$messages`.

```
$messages = array();
$message = array();
$message["role"] = "system";
$message["content"] = "this is my content for system";
$messages[] = $message;
$message["role"] = "user";
$message["content"] = "this is my content for user";
$messages[] = $message;
```

Comment: I always forget that PHP passes arrays by value. Feels icky

Comment: Yeah. Of course, I would just write `$messages = [['role' => 'system', 'content' => ...], [...]]`

Comment: Damn I have a lot to learn! Thank you both. Even though the question was duplicate I found my answer. I guess I wasn't specific enough when searching for the solution before these answers.